# Check whether this function is a metric over $\mathbb{R}$ or not?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, triangle-inequality

$\mathbb{R}$ can be viewed as the union of open-closed intervals.
$\mathbb{R}=\cup^{}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}I_n$
Where $I_n$=(n, n+1]
Then it is clear that any real number will belong to exactly one of such $I_n$'s.
Define a function
$$
d(x,y) =
\begin{cases} 
0, x=y\\
|n-m|+|x-(n+1)|+|y-(m+1)|, x \neq y \;\; x \in I_n, y\in I_m \\
\end{cases} 
$$

Now first two conditions are easy to verify.
I'm having trouble proving the triangular inequality.
Actually I was looking for metric spaces in which $1/n$ doesn't converges to 0.
So I was trying this metric.
We can start by cases for x, y, z
And if x, y, z are integers then it is easy to verify.
If x, y, z are in same $I_n$ then also I verifies that triangle inequality holds.
But I'm confused in other cases.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The map $$r : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R : x \mapsto \lfloor x \rfloor + \lceil x \rceil - x$$ is a bijection, and your metric is just $d(x,y) = |r(x) - r(y)|$. It is indeed a metric, and while $\frac 1n \to 1$ instead of $0$, the space you get is still isometric to $\Bbb R$. So you've just changed the labels. You haven't actually changed the space.

Comment: No in this space 1/n doesn't converges to 0 it is not even cauchy, because $d(1,1/n) \geq 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \in I_n, y \in I_m, $ and $z \in I_p,$ we have
$d(x, y) = |n-m| + |x-(n+1)| + |y-(m+1)| \le |n-p| + |p-m| + |x-(n+1)| + |z-(p+1)| + |z-(p+1)| + |y-(m+1)| = d(x, z) + d(y, z).$